# Finite spatial realization of relative minimal sullivan models

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, rational-homotopy-theory

In their book "Algebraic Models in Geometry" (Felix, Oprea, Tanre) the authors claim that:

"Each finite type relative minimal cdga $(∧V ⊗∧W,D)$ is the relative minimal model of a fibration $p: E → B$ where $E$ and $B$ are finite type CW-complexes." (in section 2.6.1)

I would like to construct such **finite type** CW-complexes for a few such algebras. Does anyone know a recipe (an algorithm or an instructive proof or example) of how to do that? Or where I can find one?

(Note that the standard spatial realization of a minimal cdga is not finite type.)

Comment: A good place to start would be Theorem 10.2 (ii) in Sullivan's Infinitesimal Computations in Topology (page 307, with the proof/algorithm sketched on page 310), which covers the absolute case of B = a point.